# wp_get_archives filter by range: this month, last month / this year, last year

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, archive

I'm using wp_get_archives as follows with my custom post type:

```
  <?php $args = array(
        'post_type'    => 'donation',
        'type'         => 'yearly',
        'limit'        => '1',
        'echo'         => 0
    );
    echo '<ul>'.wp_get_archives($args).'</ul>'; ?>
```

Is there a way to filter this by relative date range: 
1) this week
2) last week
3) this year
4) last year

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is way of doing it. You can use below filter for achieving it, Add .

**Filter** getarchives_where

**Reference codex:** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/getarchives_where/

**Example code:**

```
add_filter('getarchives_where', 'customFunction');
function customFunction($where, $args){
    //Add any specific post type check if required
    $startDate = date('Y');
    $endDate = date('Y', strtotime('+1 year'));
        $where.= ' AND `post_date` BETWEEN ' . $startDate . ' AND '.$endDate.'';

    return $where;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. in you example there is a fixed date range, although the date range "last year" is changing every year. How could I apply this dynamic date to your code?

Comment: Hi, I have updated code, it will search between current year and next year.